# Most "stable" color representation : RGB? HSV? CIELAB? 

Tags: colors, opencv, computer-vision

There are several color representations in computer science : the standard RGB, but also HSV, HSL, CIE XYZ, YCC, CIELAB, CIELUV, ... It seems to me that most of the times, these representation try to approximate human vision (colors perceptually identical should have similar representations)

But what I want to know is which representation is the most "stable" when it comes to pictures. I have an object, let's say a bottle of Coke, and I have thousands of pictures of this bottle, taken under very different circumstances (the main difference would be the how light or dark the picture is, but there's orientation, etc...)

My question is : what color representation will empirically give me the most stable representation of the colors of the bottle? The "red" color of the label should not vary too much. Well, I'll know it will vary, but I would like to know the most "stable" representation.

I've been taught that HSV is better than RGB for these kind of things, but I have no clue for the rest.

---

Edit (technical details) :  I take a particular point of the bottle. I pick the corresponding pixels in a thousand pictures of this point. I now have a cloud of points, that depend on the representation. I want the representation that minimizes the "size" of this cloud, for example the one that minimizes the mean distance of the points of the cloud to its barycenter.

Comment: The color of any object depends a lot on the lighting – not just the light temperature, but its spectrum as well. Objects that may have the same perceived color in sunlight (because they reflect a different spectrum that just looks the same to the human eye) need not look the same under lamplight, and LED light is a completely different story. Do you need to take this difference into account?

Comment: As far as I know there is no colourspace that tries to optimize for similarity of the "same" colour under different lighting conditions. I'm not even sure this is possible.

Comment: @Jilles : I'm pretty sure that no colour space can do it. I wondered which one was the least worse. For example, in the HSV representation, the V (value) supposedly tells how bright or dark your pixel is. If you normalize your pictures so that they all have same mean brightness (and variance) perhaps then it becomes a "good" colour space?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to check out http://www.cs.harvard.edu/~sjg/papers/cspace.pdf, which proposes a new colorspace apparently designed to address this precise question.

Comment: which channel of this colorspace should be used for a lighting invariant gradient measure? Any inputs from having used it yourselves?

Comment: Presumably the way to bring the colors back to RGB (after performing computations in the illumination-invariant new color space by premultiplying by B, component wise natural log, and then premultiplying with A) is to invert the conversion (Premultiplying with the inverse of A, component wise `exp()`, premultiply with the inverse of B)? @AruniRC I don't think that's how it works, the lighting invariance will make it such that the gradient on the 3 channels will be (more) lighting invariant, all 3 can still change due to lighting changes, however.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a colourspace that does what you want, but I do have some remarks:

RGB closely matches the way colours are displayed to us on monitors. It is one of the worst colourspaces available in terms of approximating human perception.

As for the other colourspaces: Some try to make sure colours that are perceptually close together are also close together in the colourspace. Others also try to ensure that perceptually similar differences in colour also produce similar differences in the colourspace, regardless of where in the colourspace you are.

The first means that if you think the difference in colour between blue A, and blue B is similar to the difference in colour between the blue A and blue C, then in the colourspace the distance between blue A and blue B will be similar to the distance between blue A and blue C, and they will all three be close together in the colourspace. I think this is called a perceptually smooth colourspace. [CIE XYZ](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/CIE_XYZ_color_space) is an example of this.

The second means that if you think the difference in colour between blue A and blue B is similar to the difference in colour between red A and red B then in the colourspace the distance between blue A and blue B will be similar to the difference between red A and red B. This is called a perceptually uniform colourspace. [CIE Lab](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lab_color_space) is an example of this.

---

[edit 2011-07-29] As for your problem: Any of HSV, HSL, CIE XYZ, YCC, CIELAB, CIELUV, YUV separate out the illumination from the colour info in some way, so those are the better options. They provide some immunity from illumination changes, but won't help you when the colour temperature changes drastically or coloured light is used. XYZ and YUV are computationally less expensive to get to from RGB (which is what most cameras give you) but also less "good" than HSV, HSL, or CIELAB (the latter is often considered one of the best, but it is also one of the most difficult).

Depending on what you are searching for you could calibrate the [color balance](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Color_balance) of the images. For example: suppose you are matching coca cola logos: You know that the letters in the logo are always white. So if they are not in your image you can use the colour they have to correct that, which gives you information about the other colours.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your thorough explanation! You helped me understand better the reasons that led to the creation of other color representations. And in a way, you explained (correct me if I'm wrong) that if I showed a certain colour to a human being and asked him to point the closest colour in a pallette of 10 predefined colours, he would point the one with the closest values if the color representation is good. But I wondered if I took a thousand pictures of the same colour, would the cameras tell me also that the pixels have a close representation? Because our brain do incredible things.

Answer (score 2):

Our perception of the color of something is mostly determined by its hue; a colorspace such as HSV which gives a single value representing hue will work best.

The eye is a remarkable instrument though, and knowing the color of a single point is not enough. If the entire scene has a yellow or blue tint to it, the eye will compensate and your perception will be of a purer color - the orange Coke bottle will appear to be redder than it is. Likewise with darkness and brightness. If possible, you should try to compensate the image before taking the color sample.

Comment: True, true, true! I only thought about normalizing the brightness (same mean and same variance across my pictures). Thanks for the answer! (though it does not exactly answer what I asked ^^)