# Java color detection

Tags: java, algorithm, colors, computer-vision, detection

I am implementing  algorithm in java which select a portion of image as marker.
My problem is

1) After selecting the marker area, how do i get the specific mean value of marker color in RGB as the number of pixels with a small difference in color.

2) How can i find marker value, meaning the threshold value for the color, based on the previous marker selection.

Please provide an algorithm and if posssible, an implementation in java.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to get an answer, you should give the readers a hint to what you have tried so far, and where you got stuck. The more specifically the better

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you tried, and where you're stuck, but here goes:

1. To get a mean color your best bet is to try to find the median value for the three channels (R, G and B) separately and use that as the mean. Due to specific qualities of the RGB color space, the mean is very vulnerable to outliers, the median less so.
2. I assume you want to select all colors that are similar to your marker color. To do that you could select all pixels where the color is less small [euclidean distance](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to your median RGB color selected above.

If this does not work for you you could look into [alternative colorspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857684/most-stable-color-representation-rgb-hsv-cielab). But I think the above should be enough.