# Java: how to detect colorclusters in an image

Tags: java

I´m looking forward to writing a method in Java wich detects and also stores "colorclusters" in seperate files.

For instance: a color cluster could be a green rectangle or any other section of a picture which contains very similar pixelcolors in range:

[image]

Unfortunately, I´ve already tried thought a thousand ways of how to solve this issue but nothing worked so far. Does anyone know if there is already such a method or how to solve this problem?

Comment: 'I´ve already tried thought a thousand ways'. Show us (at least) one of your faile attempts.

Comment: 'any other section of a picture wich contains very similar pixelcolors in range'. Please define 'section', 'contains', 'very similar', 'in range'.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. But see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506579/java-color-detection) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the concept of a "Graphics Kernel"

Basically it is a relocatable array representing a pixel and its neighbors, coupled with an algorithm to determine some interesting quality about the pixel.

Kernels are evaluated against each pixel to give a value.  An pseudocode example of a kernel might be.

```
value = sum of color_distance_between pixel and all neighbors
```

If the value is zero, then the pixel should be exactly the same as it's neighbors.  If the value is not zero, then it had differing neighbors.  Take care that all color distances are positive, or you might have color differences that cancel each other out.

Then your program runs through each pixel, determining if it is similar to it's neighbors.  Large regions of pixels with no color distance would be grouped and any pixel within that group has roughly the same color.

Comment: Thanks, I´ll try around a bit with this. ^^