# LAB color space (vs RGB or HSV) - OpenCV example?

Tags: opencv, colors

Good afternoon,

I've used the RGB and HSV color spaces in OpenCV extensively and would like to branch my knowledge out to LAB as well, however I'm having a hard time getting started.  At this point my questions are:

1) What is the advantage of LAB over HSV?  I'm well aware of the advantage of HSV over RGB (generally illumination invariance) but I can't seem to find a good source clarifying the advantage of LAB vs HSV.  I presume LAB must be advantageous in at least some situations since it involves processing two color channels instead of one.

2) Is anybody aware of a good OpenCV example of a vision task that won't work using HSV but will work with LAB?  I can find plenty of examples of vision tasks that can't be done with RGB but can with HSV, however I can't seem to find an example that can't be done with HSV but can with LAB.

I've found some sources that offer some degree of assistance on this topic such as:

[Most "stable" color representation : RGB? HSV? CIELAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857684/most-stable-color-representation-rgb-hsv-cielab)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-RGB-HSV-and-CIE-Lab

But none of these answers either of the above questions directly, especially the 2nd.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1)
Lab color space is more perceptually **linear** than other color spaces. Perceptually linear means that a change of the same amount in a color value should produce a change of about the same visual importance.
It is important especially when you try to measure the perceptually difference of two colors. for more information see [Color difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) wiki.

In addition [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) wiki page list some other [Disadvantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Disadvantages) of HSV, which also shows the superiority of Lab color space.

2)
I have never seen an OpenCV example in this case!? but there are many applications Like Adobe Photoshop that allow image editing using "Lab mode"

Comment: is it same to convert color from RGBA to CIELAB color space (white point D65) for a colorful picture and a while/black picture? and how to convert? is CIELAB the best color space to change brightness, contrast, saturation?