# How to get color name by rgb values?

Tags: java, image-processing

In Java how to get the **most common color Name** by rgb values from an image . can any one help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20056186/1175253

Comment: @Sam How can it **possibly** be a duplicate if the "original" is written in C++ and this in Java? Maybe Java **does** have an easy way to figure it out.

Comment: @skiwi Neither the JRE nor the C or C++ standard library does provide a way to do this, AFAIK. So I consider the language to be rather unimportant. btw. I did NOT vote for close.

Comment: You want an exact match for each **most common color Name** or a way to qunatize your RGB to one of these colors even though it's not an exact match. e.g. if RGB values are 0-10 put `Color.Black` etc?

Comment: Definitely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126029/java-color-code-convert-to-color-name And probably http://imgs.xkcd.com/blag/doghouse_color_wheel_altered.png

Comment: Use one of the many [RGB to Color Name](http://web.njit.edu/~kevin/rgb.txt.html) charts on the Interwebs to create your own Map<Color, String>.

Comment: There are many ways you can do this.  Methods like the above, or one thing that is possible is to get a common colour chart, such as http://www.immigration-usa.com/html_colors.html, convert each colour into CIE L*a*b*.  Given a query colour, you can find the CIE76 (Euclidean) distance between each of these and choose the colour with the smallest distance.  This will be the colour that is closest to the one in the colour chart and so you can classify that query colour to be that one from the chart. FWIW, finding distances in RGB space is a very bad way of mimicking human perception of colour.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way here is the code ,and it works for me . First I get the common color from image ,i used **[getting most common color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427200/getting-the-most-common-color-of-a-image)** in the RGB value and i passed those value to  **getColorNameFromRgb(int r, int g, int b)**

```
public class ColorUtils {


/**
 * Initialize the color list that we have.
 */
private ArrayList<ColorName> initColorList() {
    ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = new ArrayList<ColorName>();
    colorList.add(new ColorName("AliceBlue", 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("AntiqueWhite", 0xFA, 0xEB, 0xD7));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Aqua", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Aquamarine", 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xD4));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Azure", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Beige", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xDC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Bisque", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xC4));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Black", 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("BlanchedAlmond", 0xFF, 0xEB, 0xCD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Blue", 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("BlueViolet", 0x8A, 0x2B, 0xE2));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Brown", 0xA5, 0x2A, 0x2A));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("BurlyWood", 0xDE, 0xB8, 0x87));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("CadetBlue", 0x5F, 0x9E, 0xA0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Chartreuse", 0x7F, 0xFF, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Chocolate", 0xD2, 0x69, 0x1E));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Coral", 0xFF, 0x7F, 0x50));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("CornflowerBlue", 0x64, 0x95, 0xED));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Cornsilk", 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xDC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Crimson", 0xDC, 0x14, 0x3C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Cyan", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkBlue", 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkCyan", 0x00, 0x8B, 0x8B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGoldenRod", 0xB8, 0x86, 0x0B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGray", 0xA9, 0xA9, 0xA9));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGreen", 0x00, 0x64, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkKhaki", 0xBD, 0xB7, 0x6B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkMagenta", 0x8B, 0x00, 0x8B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOliveGreen", 0x55, 0x6B, 0x2F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOrange", 0xFF, 0x8C, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOrchid", 0x99, 0x32, 0xCC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkRed", 0x8B, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSalmon", 0xE9, 0x96, 0x7A));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSeaGreen", 0x8F, 0xBC, 0x8F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSlateBlue", 0x48, 0x3D, 0x8B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSlateGray", 0x2F, 0x4F, 0x4F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkTurquoise", 0x00, 0xCE, 0xD1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkViolet", 0x94, 0x00, 0xD3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DeepPink", 0xFF, 0x14, 0x93));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DeepSkyBlue", 0x00, 0xBF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DimGray", 0x69, 0x69, 0x69));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DodgerBlue", 0x1E, 0x90, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("FireBrick", 0xB2, 0x22, 0x22));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("FloralWhite", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xF0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("ForestGreen", 0x22, 0x8B, 0x22));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Fuchsia", 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Gainsboro", 0xDC, 0xDC, 0xDC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("GhostWhite", 0xF8, 0xF8, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Gold", 0xFF, 0xD7, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("GoldenRod", 0xDA, 0xA5, 0x20));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Gray", 0x80, 0x80, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Green", 0x00, 0x80, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("GreenYellow", 0xAD, 0xFF, 0x2F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("HoneyDew", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xF0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("HotPink", 0xFF, 0x69, 0xB4));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("IndianRed", 0xCD, 0x5C, 0x5C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Indigo", 0x4B, 0x00, 0x82));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Ivory", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Khaki", 0xF0, 0xE6, 0x8C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Lavender", 0xE6, 0xE6, 0xFA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LavenderBlush", 0xFF, 0xF0, 0xF5));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LawnGreen", 0x7C, 0xFC, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LemonChiffon", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xCD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightBlue", 0xAD, 0xD8, 0xE6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightCoral", 0xF0, 0x80, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightCyan", 0xE0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGoldenRodYellow", 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xD2));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGray", 0xD3, 0xD3, 0xD3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGreen", 0x90, 0xEE, 0x90));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightPink", 0xFF, 0xB6, 0xC1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSalmon", 0xFF, 0xA0, 0x7A));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSeaGreen", 0x20, 0xB2, 0xAA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSkyBlue", 0x87, 0xCE, 0xFA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSlateGray", 0x77, 0x88, 0x99));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSteelBlue", 0xB0, 0xC4, 0xDE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightYellow", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Lime", 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LimeGreen", 0x32, 0xCD, 0x32));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Linen", 0xFA, 0xF0, 0xE6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Magenta", 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Maroon", 0x80, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumAquaMarine", 0x66, 0xCD, 0xAA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumBlue", 0x00, 0x00, 0xCD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumOrchid", 0xBA, 0x55, 0xD3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumPurple", 0x93, 0x70, 0xDB));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSeaGreen", 0x3C, 0xB3, 0x71));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSlateBlue", 0x7B, 0x68, 0xEE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSpringGreen", 0x00, 0xFA, 0x9A));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumTurquoise", 0x48, 0xD1, 0xCC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumVioletRed", 0xC7, 0x15, 0x85));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MidnightBlue", 0x19, 0x19, 0x70));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MintCream", 0xF5, 0xFF, 0xFA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MistyRose", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xE1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Moccasin", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xB5));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("NavajoWhite", 0xFF, 0xDE, 0xAD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Navy", 0x00, 0x00, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("OldLace", 0xFD, 0xF5, 0xE6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Olive", 0x80, 0x80, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("OliveDrab", 0x6B, 0x8E, 0x23));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Orange", 0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("OrangeRed", 0xFF, 0x45, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Orchid", 0xDA, 0x70, 0xD6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleGoldenRod", 0xEE, 0xE8, 0xAA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleGreen", 0x98, 0xFB, 0x98));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleTurquoise", 0xAF, 0xEE, 0xEE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleVioletRed", 0xDB, 0x70, 0x93));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PapayaWhip", 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xD5));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PeachPuff", 0xFF, 0xDA, 0xB9));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Peru", 0xCD, 0x85, 0x3F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Pink", 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xCB));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Plum", 0xDD, 0xA0, 0xDD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PowderBlue", 0xB0, 0xE0, 0xE6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Purple", 0x80, 0x00, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Red", 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("RosyBrown", 0xBC, 0x8F, 0x8F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("RoyalBlue", 0x41, 0x69, 0xE1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SaddleBrown", 0x8B, 0x45, 0x13));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Salmon", 0xFA, 0x80, 0x72));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SandyBrown", 0xF4, 0xA4, 0x60));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SeaGreen", 0x2E, 0x8B, 0x57));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SeaShell", 0xFF, 0xF5, 0xEE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Sienna", 0xA0, 0x52, 0x2D));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Silver", 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SkyBlue", 0x87, 0xCE, 0xEB));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SlateBlue", 0x6A, 0x5A, 0xCD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SlateGray", 0x70, 0x80, 0x90));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Snow", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xFA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SpringGreen", 0x00, 0xFF, 0x7F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SteelBlue", 0x46, 0x82, 0xB4));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Tan", 0xD2, 0xB4, 0x8C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Teal", 0x00, 0x80, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Thistle", 0xD8, 0xBF, 0xD8));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Tomato", 0xFF, 0x63, 0x47));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Turquoise", 0x40, 0xE0, 0xD0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Violet", 0xEE, 0x82, 0xEE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Wheat", 0xF5, 0xDE, 0xB3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("White", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("WhiteSmoke", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xF5));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Yellow", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("YellowGreen", 0x9A, 0xCD, 0x32));
    return colorList;
}


public  String getColorNameFromRgb(int r, int g, int b) {
    ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = initColorList();
    ColorName closestMatch = null;
    int minMSE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int mse;
    for (ColorName c : colorList) {
        mse = c.computeMSE(r, g, b);
        if (mse < minMSE) {
            minMSE = mse;
            closestMatch = c;
        }
    }

    if (closestMatch != null) {
        return closestMatch.getName();
    } else {
        return "No matched color name.";
    }
}

public class ColorName {
    public int r, g, b;
    public String name;

    public ColorName(String name, int r, int g, int b) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int computeMSE(int pixR, int pixG, int pixB) {
        return (int) (((pixR - r) * (pixR - r) + (pixG - g) * (pixG - g) + (pixB - b)
                * (pixB - b)) / 3);
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public int getG() {
        return g;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



}
```

Comment: Blatantly copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/20670056/3182664 without giving a reference...