# How to compare multiple values in a function that takes only 2 parameters?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to build a hexadecimal color comparator which compares values in an array and deletes the ones that are similar keeping colors with the most pixels.

Here's an example of what the **input** looks like, the length of the array can change from 1 to more :

```
[…]
0: Array [ "ffffff", 12992 ]
1: Array [ "da542f", 3117 ] #similar
2: Array [ "da5630", 60 ]   #similar
length: 3

(index: Array [hexColor, NumberOfPixel])
```

The **output** would look like this :

```
[…]
0: Array [ "ffffff", 12992 ]
1: Array [ "da542f", 3117 ]
length: 2
```

---

What I come up with, since the example below is super hardcoded and produce bugs I'd like to avoid having multiple if/else inside each other, `hexColorCalc()` function comes from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692134/detect-similar-colours-from-hex-values)** :

***[FIDDLE >](http://jsfiddle.net/qxtxstsf/)***

```
// ordered by highest pixel
colors_lst = [
  ["333333", 6421], 
  ["da542f", 3117],
  ["da5630", 60]
]

console.log(colors_lst);

function hexColorDelta(array) {
  function hexColorCalc(hex1, hex2) {
    // get red/green/blue int values of hex1
    var r1 = parseInt(hex1.substring(0, 2), 16);
    var g1 = parseInt(hex1.substring(2, 4), 16);
    var b1 = parseInt(hex1.substring(4, 6), 16);
    // get red/green/blue int values of hex2
    var r2 = parseInt(hex2.substring(0, 2), 16);
    var g2 = parseInt(hex2.substring(2, 4), 16);
    var b2 = parseInt(hex2.substring(4, 6), 16);
    // calculate differences between reds, greens and blues
    var r = 255 - Math.abs(r1 - r2);
    var g = 255 - Math.abs(g1 - g2);
    var b = 255 - Math.abs(b1 - b2);
    // limit differences between 0 and 1
    r /= 255;
    g /= 255;
    b /= 255;
    // 0 means opposit colors, 1 means same colors
    return (r + g + b) / 3;
  }

  // Do nothing since nothing to compare
  if (array.length == 1) {
    console.log('length of array : 1');
    return array
  }

  // Just compare both values and erase the one with least pixel
  if (array.length == 2) {
    console.log('length of array : 2');
    var hex1 = array[0][0];
    var hex2 = array[1][0];


    if (hexColorCalc(hex1, hex2) > 0.9) {
      colors_lst = array.pop(); // Get ride of last item in array
      return colors_lst;
    }
  }

  // Problems 
  if (array.length == 3) {
    var hex1 = array[0][0];
    var hex2 = array[1][0];
    var hex3 = array[2][0];

    // if True, other if/else below won't be working
    if (hexColorCalc(hex1, hex2) > 0.9) {
      array.splice(2, 1);
    }

    if (hexColorCalc(hex1, hex3) > 0.9) {
      array.splice(3, 1);
    }

    if (hexColorCalc(hex2, hex3) > 0.9) {
      array.splice(2, 1);
    }

    return array
  }
}

console.log(hexColorDelta(colors_lst));
```

I commented out how the code works, I'm having some trouble understanding the correct algorithm for this problem. How can I avoid the hardcoding and return a proper list without similarities?

Comment: seems like you need the combinations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241174/javascript-generating-all-combinations-of-elements-in-a-single-array-in-pairs

Comment: How exactly do you define "similarity"? `da542f` and `da5630` are pretty close to each other but not identical. Where's the threshold?

Comment: there are still some issues as you will get different number of colors depending on the order in which the colors are compared and removed. I suggest internet search for JavaScript [color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) and possibly use any of the available implementations https://github.com/leeoniya/RgbQuant.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid excessive usage of `if`, especially for larger array where combination will explode, you can rely on loops. Below is the solution I proposed after doing a bit of cleanup to your code:

```js
// splits the hex value to its components
function splitHex(hex) {
    return {
        r: parseInt(hex.substring(0, 2), 16),
        g: parseInt(hex.substring(2, 4), 16),
        b: parseInt(hex.substring(4, 6), 16)
    };
}

// return number between 0 (opposit colors) and 1 (same colors)
function hexColorCalc(hex1, hex2) {
    // get red/green/blue int values of hex1
    const hex1Split = splitHex(hex1);
    // get red/green/blue int values of hex2
    const hex2Split = splitHex(hex2);
    // calculate normalized differences between reds, greens and blues
    const r = 1 - Math.abs(hex1Split.r - hex2Split.r) / 255;
    const g = 1 - Math.abs(hex1Split.g - hex2Split.g) / 255;
    const b = 1 - Math.abs(hex1Split.b - hex2Split.b) / 255;

    return (r + g + b) / 3;
}

// clears array from similar colors with threshold
function hexColorDelta(array, threshold) {
    // loop through array twice as a table to get all combinations
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            // only remove the color in the second loop if similar
            if (i !== j && hexColorCalc(array[i][0], array[j][0]) > threshold) {
                array.splice(j, 1);
                j--;
            }   
        }
    }
    return array;
}

// test
const similar_1_2 = [["da542f", 3117], ["da5630", 60], ["333333", 6421]];
const similar_1_3 = [["da542f", 3117], ["333333", 6421], ["da5630", 60]];
const similar_2_3 = [["333333", 6421], ["da542f", 3117], ["da5630", 60]];
const similar_all = [["da5630", 60], ["da542f", 3117], ["da5630", 60]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(hexColorDelta(similar_1_2, 0.9)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(hexColorDelta(similar_1_3, 0.9)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(hexColorDelta(similar_2_3, 0.9)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(hexColorDelta(similar_all, 0.9)));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome answer! I see that you're using `const` instead of `var` to define variables, is there any particular reason for that ?

Comment: Thanks, and yes, `const` is better than `var` especially inside functions, as not only will it declare a scope-local variable but it will also not allow you to reassign the variable, if you want to reassign it, you can use `let`.

Answer (score -1):

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/4ph8wozd/1/

```js
// convert HEX code to RGB
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function (m, r, g, b) {
        return r + r + g + g + b + b;
    });

    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);

    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
// compare colors
function luminanace(r, g, b) {
    var colorArray = [r, g, b];
    var colorFactor;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
        colorFactor = colorArray[i] / 255;
        if (colorFactor <= 0.03928) {
            colorFactor = colorFactor / 12.92;
        } else {
            colorFactor = Math.pow(((colorFactor + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4);
        }
        colorArray[i] = colorFactor;
    }
    return (colorArray[0] * 0.2126 + colorArray[1] * 0.7152 + colorArray[2] * 0.0722) + 0.05;
}
function contrast(hex1, hex2) {
    var color1 = hexToRgb(hex1);
    var color2 = hexToRgb(hex2);
    if (color1 != null && color2 != null) {
        var result = (luminanace(color1.r, color1.g, color1.b)) / (luminanace(color2.r, color2.g, color2.b)); if (result < 1) result = 1 / result;

        // show result
        // Google says lowest:4.5 | enough:7 | good:14 | best:21
        var rgood = 7;
        var rbad = 4.5;
        contrastratio = result;
        switch (true) {
            case result >= rgood:
                contrastratiomessage = '<span class="cr-green">Text is well readable</span>';
                break;
            case result > rbad && result < rgood:
                contrastratiomessage = '<span class="cr-orange">Text is enough readable</span>';
                break;
            case result <= rbad:
                contrastratiomessage = '<span class="cr-red">Text is not readable!!!</span>';
                break;
            default:
        }
        document.getElementById('colors').innerHTML = contrastratiomessage;
    }
    console.log(result);
}
contrast('#fff000','#000fff');
```

```html
<div id="colors"></div>
```