# How to get matching colors (red and green) for a given color code (blue)

Tags: colors, hex

I am new to CSS and programming in general so I am sorry if this is a beginner question but I couldn't find a proper solution myself.

If I have a certain color code (HEX), e.g. `#028dca`, how can I get matching colors for this ?

I found a number of tools online but I only saw solutions that give me different shades of the same color whereas **I need different colors that match the above hue etc., especially red and green** - and a few more colors would be nice to have.

One of several examples I tested is the following but again I couldn't find a proper red and green tone there, just different shades of blue and orange as the complementary color (and it looked similar with other tools I checked): https://color.adobe.com

Can someone help me with this ?

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: what do you mean "matching", as in "close to"? negatives?

Comment: I mean the same hue or intensity so that they look good together when being used on a website. Specifically my problem is to find a green and red tone that works since all the tools I tested just give me other colors.

Comment: then don't use rgb. convert to HSV. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392061/algorithm-to-check-similarity-of-colors-based-on-rgb-values-or-maybe-hsv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know actually what you mean with "couldn't find a proper red and green tone". Given a particular color, it has complementary colors... it's math.
Here is the one that I use: http://croma.numixproject.org

Comment: Sorry, my English might not be that good to describe this properly but that's exactly what I was looking for. This works perfect - thanks a lot ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Coolors.co 
You can fix on colors and then try different palettes. 
The one with the color you posted would be like this - http://coolors.co/app/86615c-f1a699-028dca-79065a-02241a.

You can explore more by hitting the spacebar