# Match colors of selected regions

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project where I have to find the rectangle with similar 
color to a target box(one bounded by green box in image).
Any link or technique would be highly appreciable in this regard.

Note: I have tried euclidean distance on LAB colors but results are not promising.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm to check similarity of colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392061/algorithm-to-check-similarity-of-colors)

Comment: @TA I have already used this method but it does't solve my problem.

Comment: Please show your code, and say which part you are having trouble with.